# Time dependent workflow acction on Oppo- Account level

Tags: workflow, opportunity, visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I am creating a workflow on the opportunity level to create a task 2 weeks after the Account End Date has passed. Although it is visible on the opporunity, the parent for that field is on the account level. The creteria is the following:
- Ipportunity stage is processed
- Opportunity Location is NYC

However, this workflow rule works the first time, but it does not get triggered after I change the Account End Date to an Earlier peiod. I.E 4 weeks ago from today's date. I have this workflow rule as a Time Dependent Workflow.

Can Anyone help??